# Expand sin(acot(...)) in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, trigonometry

Is there a way to expand the trigonometric function of an inverse trigonometric function? I have a long-expression `f` that contains many such subexpressions, e.g.:

- `sin(0.5 acot(x))**2`
- `cos(0.5 acot(x))**2`
- `sin(acot(x))`

These expressions can be rewritten without trigonometric functions, e.g.:

- `1/2 - 1/2 * x / sp.sqrt(x**2 + 1)`

I've tried `expand_trig` and `trigsimp` to no avail. Also, I can't find a way to directly substitute the analytical expressions in.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are the intended simplifications for `cos(0.5 acot(x))**2` and `sin(0.5 acot(x))**2`?

Comment: @NickODell The sin^2 expression is the one given. The cos^2 expression is given by 1 - sin^2. The sin(acot(x)) is 1/sqrt(x^2+1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to do this. Some examples:

```
In [1]: sin(acot(x))
Out[1]: 
       1       
───────────────
       ________
      ╱     1  
x⋅   ╱  1 + ── 
    ╱        2 
  ╲╱        x  

In [2]: sin(acot(x)/2)**2
Out[2]: 
   2⎛acot(x)⎞
sin ⎜───────⎟
    ⎝   2   ⎠

In [3]: e = sin(acot(x)/2)**2

In [4]: e.rewrite(log)
Out[4]: 
    ⎛  ⎛   ⎛    ⅈ⎞      ⎛    ⅈ⎞⎞⎞
    ⎜ⅈ⋅⎜log⎜1 - ─⎟ - log⎜1 + ─⎟⎟⎟
   2⎜  ⎝   ⎝    x⎠      ⎝    x⎠⎠⎟
sin ⎜───────────────────────────⎟
    ⎝             4             ⎠

In [5]: e.rewrite(log).rewrite(exp)
Out[5]: 
      ⎛   ⎛      _______       _______⎞ ⎞
      ⎜   ⎜     ╱     ⅈ       ╱     ⅈ ⎟ ⎟
      ⎜   ⎜  4 ╱  1 - ─    4 ╱  1 + ─ ⎟ ⎟
      ⎜   ⎜  ╲╱       x    ╲╱       x ⎟ ⎟
      ⎜-ⅈ⋅⎜- ─────────── + ───────────⎟ ⎟
      ⎜   ⎜      _______       _______⎟ ⎟
      ⎜   ⎜     ╱     ⅈ       ╱     ⅈ ⎟ ⎟
      ⎜   ⎜  4 ╱  1 + ─    4 ╱  1 - ─ ⎟ ⎟
      ⎜   ⎝  ╲╱       x    ╲╱       x ⎠ ⎟
 2⋅log⎜─────────────────────────────────⎟
      ⎝                2                ⎠
ℯ                                        

In [6]: e.rewrite(log).rewrite(exp).expand()
Out[6]: 
       _______             _______ 
      ╱     ⅈ             ╱     ⅈ  
     ╱  1 - ─            ╱  1 + ─  
   ╲╱       x     1    ╲╱       x  
- ───────────── + ─ - ─────────────
        _______   2         _______
       ╱     ⅈ             ╱     ⅈ 
  4⋅  ╱  1 + ─        4⋅  ╱  1 - ─ 
    ╲╱       x          ╲╱       x 

In [7]: simplify(_)
Out[7]: 
1               1            
─ - ─────────────────────────
2         _______     _______
         ╱     ⅈ     ╱     ⅈ 
    2⋅  ╱  1 - ─ ⋅  ╱  1 + ─ 
      ╲╱       x  ╲╱       x
```

Some cases will work differently if you declare `x` as real or positive e.g. `x = symbols('x', real=True)`.